# Nodej Mongoose findOneAndUpdate is not a function error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I have following mongoose schema

```
const DeptSchema=new Schema({
  deptname:{type: String}
  isActive:{type:Boolean,default:true}
  });
module.exports=mongoose.model('Dept',DeptSchema, 'dept');
```

Than when I insert in mongo db using follwing

```
 insertDept(req, res, callback){
 var query={'_id' : req._id};
 Dept.findOneAndUpdate(query, {$push:{dept: req.dept}}, {upsert:true}, (err, depts)=>{
       if(err){
                return callback(err);
        }
        return callback(null, depts);
       });
}

When I run this code I get error  "TypeError: Dept.findOeAndUpdate is not a function"
```

I spent quite a bit of time on it. Every thing is fine I can see the object data being received but at inserting in the mongodb it gives the error. 
I already tried some other similar question here but no luck. 
Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: `Models.Dept.findOneAndUpdate()`

Comment: how is `Dept` variable set?

Comment: You'll have code that does something like `var Dept = new Dept()` and that's wrong. What you want is `var Dept = require('../models/dept')` or `var Dept = mongoose.model('Dept')` where the latter basically "retrieves" from what you declared with mongoose earlier. The former is a basic `require()`. But the error you get basically means you are trying to use an "instance" instead of importing the "Model".